# TabCMD in Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, tableau-api

I am having issues converting a bat command to my Powershell script. I am trying to run TabCMD (Tableau Command) in my PS script.

The below bat file works: tabCMD.bat

```
cd C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau 9.0\bin
tableau refreshextract --server "https://online.tableausoftware.com" --username "myEmail@email.com" --password "password" --site "gameMetrics" --project "acquisition" --datasource "VisExtract"
```

I want to translate this into a Powershell script: PSTabCMD.ps1

```
$server='https://online.tableausoftware.com'
$username='myEmail@email.com'
$password='password'
$site='gameMetrics'
$project='acquisition'
$datasource='VisExtract'


Set-Location "C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau 9.0\bin"

$TabCMD = "tableau refreshextract --server $server --username $username --password $password --site $site --project $project --datasource $datasource"

Invoke-Expression -Command:$TabCMD

write-host 'Command complete!!'
```

I get the below error:

```
'tableau : The term 'tableau' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.'
```

I've also tried changing the Invoke-Expression to *& "$TabCMD"* and *start-process $TabCMD* but those don't work either.

I need to update several extracts and don't want to call a bunch of bat files.

Does anyone know how to run this TabCMD command within Powershell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `tableau` to `.\tableau` and it will probably work.  PowerShell doesn't let you run things in the current directory without explicitly referencing the current directory.